qt5_create_translation behaviour different than lupdate tool
I am working in a Cmake project which makes use of qt5_create_translation utility to update the ts file at each build :
qt5_create_translation(QM_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} gui/translations/translation.source.ts OPTIONS -locations none -no-ui-lines -no-obsolete)

The problem is that each time it runs, it doesn't consider the original translation.source.ts file and detects all strings as new :
Updating '[...]/gui/translations/translation.source.ts'...
    Found 1707 source text(s) (1707 new and 0 already existing)

This is impractical as it makes translator comments vanish at each run, among other problems.
When I run lupdate manually though, this does not happen :
lupdate [...] -ts gui/translations/translation.source.ts -locations none -no-ui-lines -no-obsolete
Scanning directory '[...]'...
Updating 'gui/translations/translation.source.ts'...
    Found 1707 source text(s) (4 new and 1703 already existing)
    Removed 10 obsolete entries
    Same-text heuristic provided 33 translation(s)

You can see from the output that lupdate correctly updated the ts file instead of recreating it from scratch.
Where is the issue with qt5_create_translation in my Cmake file?
